# How to work with Serias in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
for i,r in data.iterrows():
    print(r)
```

a row is a Serias object and print output is like :

```
QuantifierId
18     0.0
19     0.0
20     0.0
21     NaN
23     NaN
24     NaN
25     NaN
26     NaN
27     NaN
28     NaN
63     NaN
64     NaN
81     NaN
82     NaN
83     NaN
84     NaN
85     NaN
86     NaN
87     NaN
88     NaN
89     NaN
91     NaN
93     NaN
94     NaN
95     NaN
96     NaN
121    NaN
Name: 52466, dtype: float64
```

I want to :

1. remove all QuantifierIds with value == Nan or 0 (and retain all QuantifierIds with value==1)
2. get that Name field from each row

How to do that?

Comment: Have you tried searching for similar problems? What issues did you face with those solutions?

Comment: yes i didnt find an answer, otherwise i wouldnt ask

Comment: if you just want fields with id == 1 you can just slice it `data = data[data==1]`, otherwise you can use `dropna()` to remove nans and then slice with `data = data[data != 0]`

Answer (score 1):

> 1. remove all QuantifierIds with value == Nan or 0 (and retain all
>      QuantifierIds with value==1)

```
data = data.loc[(data.QuantifierId.notnull()) & (data.QuantifierId != 0)]
```

> 2. get that Name field from each row

```
data.index.tolist()
```